# Write down the state space realization of the following ODE $mx''+Bx'+kx(1+ax^2)=u$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

My original ODE was

$$m{x}''+\beta {x}'+\kappa x(1+ax^{^{2}})=u$$ however the term $(1+ax^2)$ it is confusing me

What I did was to change my $x$ to $x_1=x$; $x_2=x'=x_1'$ in order to find the state space matrix $A$. However I still have a non-linear term; then I found the partial derivatives with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $u$, then my $A$ matrix became.

I think I have to linearize the system around an equilibrium point, however the HW does not specify an exact equilibrium point for $x$; it just states that the output is the position of the mass. Should I assume that $x=0$?
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
\frac{-k}{m}-3\frac{kax^{2}}{m} & \frac{-b}{m}
\end{bmatrix}x + \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1/m
\end{bmatrix}u
$$

My final goal is to find the poles of the system  by finding the $det(sI-A)=0$ in order to design a PID or PI controller

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand your matrix. Go to this website: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php Use it to build LaTeX for the matrix. Then post the resulting code here for the equation, wrapping the code in two double-dollar signs, \$\$: see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is a nonlinear Duffing-type equation

$$m\ddot{x}+\beta \dot{x}+\kappa x(1+ax^{^{2}})=u.$$

introduce $x=x_1,\dot{x}=\dot{x}_1=x_2, \ddot{x}=\dot{x}_2$ to obtain the state space representation

$$\dot{x}_1 = x_2$$
$$\dot{x}_2 = -\dfrac{\kappa}{m} x_1(1+ax_1^2)-\dfrac{\beta}{m}x_2+\dfrac{1}{m}u.$$

Note, that you cannot put this into the form

$$\boldsymbol{\dot{x}}=\boldsymbol{Ax}+\boldsymbol{b}u$$

because your equation is nonlinear.

In order to design a linear controller for this system, you will have to linearize the system at a specific operating point $x_{1,\text{ref}},x_{2,\text{ref}}$ and $u_\text{ref}$. If you are only interested in the output $y=x_1=x$ then you can also use exact feedback linearization, which helps you to guarantee that you do not lose important dynamics, which would happen if you would use standard linearization on the system.

Linearization of an operating point $\boldsymbol{x}_\text{OP}$ and $\boldsymbol{u}_\text{OP}$ of the differential equation

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\boldsymbol{f}\left(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{u} \right)$$

is given as

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x}_\text{OP} \right]=\boldsymbol{f}\left(\boldsymbol{x}_\text{OP},\boldsymbol{u}_\text{OP}\right)+\left.\dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{f}}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}}\right|_{\boldsymbol{x}_\text{OP},\boldsymbol{u}_\text{OP}}\left[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x}_\text{OP} \right]+\left.\dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{f}}{\partial \boldsymbol{u}}\right|_{\boldsymbol{x}_\text{OP},\boldsymbol{u}_\text{OP}}\left[\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{u}_\text{OP} \right]$$

As an example, I will show this for your equation at $x_{1,\text{ref}}=x_{2,\text{ref}}=0$ and $u_\text{ref}=0$ as the reference point.

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[x_1-x_{1,\text{ref}}\right]=0+\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1-x_{1,\text{ref}}\\x_2-x_{2,\text{ref}} \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u-u_\text{ref}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[x_2-x_{2,\text{ref}}\right]=0+\begin{bmatrix}-\dfrac{k}{m}-\dfrac{3ka}{m}x_{1,\text{ref}}&-\dfrac{\beta}{m} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1-x_{1,\text{ref}}\\x_2-x_{2,\text{ref}} \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{1}{m} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u-u_\text{ref}\end{bmatrix}$$

Using your reference point will lead to

$$\dot{x}_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\dot{x}_2=\begin{bmatrix}-\dfrac{k}{m}&-\dfrac{\beta}{m} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{1}{m} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\end{bmatrix}.$$

You should be able to deduce $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ from this.

Comment: Thanks, Yes that is exactly my confusion! I need to linearize the system in terms of it's parameters $k,m,B$. Assuming the output is the position of the mass. If I assume no movement, no input force, then $x^2$ becomes 0 - This makes the system stable - I know because previous hw, the system was linear after the state space representation. My question is how I can linearize the $x^2$

Comment: I added a new section to my answer explaining the linearization.

Comment: Thanks for all the help MrYouMath - That is what I did and that is what I got. Your comment about the Duffing type equation also help me understand more about the problem and confirm that I was on the right path